# What is S#arp architecture?

Tags: .net, s#arp-architecture

I want to get brief awareness of S#arp architecture. What is difference between Sharp and MVC? 
**Edited:** 
Is any template available like MVC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S#harp is a web framework that makes building maintainable MVC apps easier. Found this quote:

> Pronounced "Sharp Architecture," this
>   is a solid architectural foundation
>   for rapidly building maintainable web
>   applications leveraging the ASP.NET
>   MVC framework with NHibernate. The
>   primary advantage to be sought in
>   using any architectural framework is
>   to decrease the code one has to write
>   while increasing the quality of the
>   end product. A framework should enable
>   developers to spend little time on
>   infrastructure details while allowing
>   them to focus their attentions on the
>   domain and user experience.
>   Accordingly, S#arp Architecture
>   adheres to the following key
>   principles:
>
> > - Focused on Domain Driven Design
> > - Loosely Coupled Preconfigured
> > - Infrastructure Open Ended Presentation

Comment: is this means, it is nothing but the architecture that having asp.net MVC application and connected with NHibernete but in loosely coupled manner? nothing else ?

Comment: As I understand it it's mainly a couple of classes on which you can build your domain model.

Comment: okay ! but what is basic difference between asp.net MVC and S#arp architecture?

Answer (score 4):

S#arp Architecture has nothing to do with MVC other than the fact it implements an ASP.NET MVC front end by default.

You cannot compare MVC to S#arp Architecture as they solve different issues. S#arp Architecture is a framework designed to focus on the domain using domain driven design. It is designed to have an open ended presentation layer so you can use it with MVC, Web Forms, Console, Win Forms, WPF, Silverlight, etc... presentation layers.